# Comparing Time.now.zone to ActiveSupport::TimeZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone, activesupport

I am collecting a user's time zone during signup and storing in database with the following form (relevant part).

```
<%= a.input :time_zone, collection: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map { |zone| [zone.name, zone.name] }, required: true, label: "Select your time zone" %>
```

However, I would like to default the selection to the user's local time zone (based on OS) to speed up registration process.  I tried using

```
<%= a.input :time_zone, collection: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map { |zone| [zone.name, zone.name] }, selected: Time.now.zone, required: true, label: "Select your time zone" %>
```

but it doesn't work because Time.now.zone is "Eastern Daylight Time" and the zone name is "Eastern Time (US & Canada)".  Is there anyway to convert the Time.now.zone to the zone name .

Comment: Please also read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), in particular - the very last paragraph about "Rails Time Zone Identifiers".

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818180/ruby-rails-how-do-i-change-the-timezone-of-a-time-without-changing-the-time#answer-16819187)

Say, you want to set timezone `America/New_York` to `Time.now` (here Time.now.zone is BDT)

```
time = Time.now
offset = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('America/New_York').utc_offset()
time = time.in_time_zone("America/New_York")
time += -offset
```

So thank [j-mcnally](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1052788/j-mcnally).