# How to shift the timezone of an instance of the ruby Time object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone

I have `Time` object which I've created

```
t = Time.parse("Sat Nov 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)")
```

I would like to shift the time_zone of `t` to be represented in the `GMT -0500" timezone.

Just to for clarity, I want the new `t` to become "Fri Oct 31 2014 23:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)".

Please let me know if you need anymore information to answer. This timezone stuff gets seriously confusing.  :)

Comment: Related, but not direct duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818180/ruby-rails-how-do-i-change-the-timezone-of-a-time-without-changing-the-time and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4467781/405017

Comment: Thank you for including the clear output that you would like. Please let me know if the questions that I have marked as duplicates and related do not answer your question.

Comment: This one is really close http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467781/how-do-i-alter-the-timezone-of-a-datetime-in-ruby but it is for the `DateTime` object. It is a different method for the `Time` object. I think it's probably legitimate to leave this question open.

Comment: Although I think I have the time shift backwards. I think it shifts it to "Fri Oct 31 2014 23:00:00 GMT-500 (EST)".

Comment: What I am looking for is achieved by applying the `in_time_zone` method to the instance of the `Time` object that you want to shift.

Comment: So, I really think this shouldn't be marked as a duplicate the more I think about it. This question is for an entirely different Class and Method than the one that it is marked as a duplicate. If someone was working with Time, like I am, instaed of DateTime, then the answer for the question that this is marked as a duplicate of wouldn't help them at all.